# Either/Or fields in Django models

Tags: django, django-models, optional-parameters

I was building a django model that has two fields, only one of them is required.

```
class course_data(models.Model):
    link = models.CharField(max_length = 500, null = True, blank = True)
    uploaded_file = models.FileField(upload_to='course_files', null = True, blank = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
    description = models.TextField(null = True, blank = True)    
    applies_to = models.ManyToManyField('course')
```

I want the entry to be valid only if the "link" field is provided or if the 'uploaded_file' field is provided or both. I can't make both parameters optional since they can be both left blank. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) and override its `clean` method to get the behaviour you want. If you want to use the admin, you can add the custom behaviour with a [ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects)

Answer (score 4):

This isn't something you'd deal with in the model definition. You would handle it at the form level, by making both fields `required=False` but checking in the form's `clean()` method that one of them was supplied.

Answer (score 2):

you can override `clean` method:

```
class course_data(models.Model):
    link = models.CharField(max_length = 500, null = True, blank = True)
    uploaded_file = models.FileField(upload_to='course_files', null = True, blank = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
    description = models.TextField(null = True, blank = True)    
    applies_to = models.ManyToManyField('course')

    def clean(self):
        if self.link == None and self.uploaded_file is None:
            raise ValidationError(_('Fields uploaded_file and link required.'))
```